# Android : Make application wait till the current location is found

Tags: android, android-location

I'm trying to make my app wait till the current location is found. I've tried few different ways using `Threads` and all have failed really. I was using `wait()` and `notify()` but application just hung and never found the current location.

I amen't using google map api as it is not part of the application. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this or examples.

**EDIT :** The `Thread` I was using did not start till the user pressed a button then within `onLocationChanged` other data is processed e.g. adding the new location to ArrayList, Calculate the distance between the current and last Location as well as the Time taken to get to the new location

Comment: Are you using the GPS with LocationManager, LocationListener, etc? I ask because it's hard to understand why you wouldn't just put your code into LocationListener.onLocationChanged(), which is what gets called when the current location is found.

Comment: Yes I have the locationManager etc working but when the user presses a button to get the location I want it to wait till the current location is found before anything will happen or anything else will happen. I should have included this detail in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try starting an `AsyncTask` in `onCreate`to get the location.  Your default `onCreate` layout could be a "loading" page, then when your `AsyncTask` completes successfully with the location it draws your "real" UI.

Comment: Pretty new to AsyncTask stuff but pretty sure it would work on onClick instead of onCreate though. Thats just way wanted to do it and maybe bring up a progress dialog or similar

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand what you want to do correctly, then I would avoid making another thread in `onClick()`. Instead, `onClick()` should just request a location, display a progress dialog, and return. Since the work you want to do happens after you receive the new location, I would start an AsyncTask there. Then you finally remove the dialog box (removing it returns control to the user) when the AsyncTask finishes.

Code usually helps, so, I would put this in `onCreate()` or wherever:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.refresh();
    }
});
```

And put this in your LocationListener:

```
public void refresh() {
    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    myDialog = new ProgressDialog(myContext);
    myDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    myDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // now do work with your location, 
    // which your probably want to do in a different thread
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(new Location[] { location });
}
```

And then you need an AsyncTask, which may look like this:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Location... location) {
        // start doing your distance/directions/etc work here
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        // this gets called automatically when you're done, 
        // so release the dialog box
        myDialog.dismiss();
        myDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort of, I only want the thread/asyncTask to be run once to find the initial location of the device after that will just use `onLocationChanged` to provide all the later locations. Due to the fact that if I had used `getLastKnownLocation(String provider)` it may put the distance of the fairly big error.

Comment: @Droid_Interceptor Yeah, `getLastKnownLocation()` sometimes gets very old (like 24-hour old) data. But I'm not sure you need threads/`AsyncTask` at all. Just call `requestLocationUpdates()`. Android will call `onLocationChanged()` when you've got a location. The purpose of the callback systems that Android uses is that you don't need threads to just wait. `AsyncTask` is for doing active work, not for waiting on the GPS.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Blackwell I think I just need to have another crack at it, was just getting bit frustrated with it last night. Think the main problem might be that the LocationListener is implemented as a seperate class rather than a inner class so it is seperated from the Activity and thus calling a getCurrentLocation() method is returning null before can get a location.